# Time function in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I'm about to implement a small program where i need the elapsed seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970 to 00:00:00 UTC on June 22, 2009. Could anyone please point me in the right direction, as to how to achieve this.

Comment: Have a look at `long Date.getTime()`.

Comment: Oh come on. Did you even try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    calendar.set(2009, 5, 22, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println("ms: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

If you want to parse String representation of Date, take a look at SimpleDateFormat. Although it was suggested in one answer, you should avoid using static instances as they are not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Sure: It's easy to get milliseconds since the epoch:

```
long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Here's how you get milliseconds from a specific time:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss";
private static final DateFormat FORMATTER;

static {
    FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_PATTERN);
    FORMATTER.setLenient(false);
}

public static long getDateMilliseconds(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    return FORMATTER.parse(dateStr).getTime();
}
```

Comment: Yes i know but i need the seconds elapsed between epoch and a specific time fx. 22 June 2009 00:00:00 UTC